# How to have a public trait with a pub(crate) method in a library?

Tags: rust, visibility, traits

Suppose I have the following trait in a library:

```rust
pub trait Foo {
    fn public_op(&self);
    fn internal_op(&self);
}
```

This trait is then implemented for a bunch of structs in this library:

```rust
pub struct One {}

impl Foo for One {
    fn public_op(&self) {}
    fn internal_op(&self) {}
}

pub struct Two {}

impl Foo for Two {
    fn public_op(&self) {}
    fn internal_op(&self) {}
}
```

And there is a public function in this library which receives the trait type:

```rust
pub fn process(obj: &dyn Foo) {
    obj.public_op();
    obj.internal_op();
}
```

The problem is that, since `Foo` trait is public in the library, the method `internal_op` is also public... but in fact it should have `pub(crate)` visibility, because it must be used inside the library only.

As far as I know, all methods of a trait are public, so how can I redesign this problem?

Comment: What is the relationship between `public_op` and `internal_op` -- is one implemented in terms of the other? For instance, can someone implement `Foo` for an external type by only implementing `public_op`? Or can `Foo` not be implemented externally at all?

Comment: @trentcl No relationship between `public_op` and `internal_op`, other than the object passed to `process` must implement both.

Answer (score 5):

You can split `Foo` into two traits, one public and one private.

```
pub trait Foo: private::Foo {
    fn public_op(&self);
}

pub(crate) mod private {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn internal_op(&self);
    }
}
```

Then implement them both in your library crate as follows:

```
pub struct One {}

impl Foo for One {
    fn public_op(&self) {}
}

impl private::Foo for One {
    fn internal_op(&self) {}
}
```

Then using from outside the library crate would look like:

```
fn main() {
   let one = One {};
   one.public_op(); // works
   process(&one); // works
   
   //one.internal_op(); // error[E0599]: no method named `internal_op`...
}
```

This does mean that its impossible for users of your library to implement `Foo` as `Foo` is now effectively a ['sealed trait'](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#sealed-traits-protect-against-downstream-implementations-c-sealed).

See Jack Wrenn's [blog post](https://jack.wrenn.fyi/blog/private-trait-methods/) for a discussion of this and alternative approaches.

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2566e5c416c7c8caf8e83c1fcf8b6570)

Comment: Nice. The supertrait relationship here is probably what OP wants, but this isn't the only way you could interpret it -- for instance, you could make `private::Foo` require `crate::Foo` instead, which would allow external code to implement `crate::Foo`, but you'd have to use `private::Foo` in the API of `process`. [This blog post](https://jack.wrenn.fyi/blog/private-trait-methods/) contains some more ideas that build on the same public-in-private trick.

Comment: haha! I just linked that blog post and addressed this issue while you were commenting!

Comment: I just tried the "sealed trait" described. It forbids user implementation of the "private trait", but the methods are sill there, visible to the end user. What I'm after is to **prevent the methods to be called**, not simply prevent the their implementation in an user struct.

Comment: @rodrigocfd It will indeed prevent `internal_op` method being called (this was the whole point!).

Try the playground link at the end of my answer and uncomment the `one.internal_op();` call in `main()`. Rustc will respond with the error: ```error[E0599]: no method named `internal_op` found for struct `One` in the current scope```.

Maybe your IDE is confused by this 'trick', and provides autocompletion suggestion for the hidden method, I know `intellij-rust` does this.